# How to use RewriteEngine in .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My current .htaccess file contains this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*jpg$|.*gif$|.*png$|.*mp3$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /viewed.php?file=$1
```

I want to change it so it rewrites the URL to /viewed.php?file=$1 ($1 being file path) if the extension is *not* .php, but I don't know how to do that. (I found that code on another post and added my own extensions to the list)

If someone could link me to an explanation of how Rewrite Conditions work that would be great because I don't understand how to make them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite all, if not `.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^.*\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /viewed.php?file=$1 [L]
```

Documentation:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Learn RegEx:
https://regexone.com/